# Angular 6 - How to tell Angular to use the data-prefix for custom attributes instead putting them directly on the DOM elements?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, custom-attributes

I am using the angular-cli and the @ng-toolkit/universal package to make my angular project SEO friendly. I would like to validate my website/html with a validator. The problem is, that angular is setting custom attributes directly on the DOM element instead to use the **-data prefix**. How can I tell angular to use data-attributes on default? Or how can I export an existing angular-cli project with data attribute?

instead of this output:

```
<h1 _ngcontent-c0=""> Welcome! </h1>
```

I would like to have this output:

```
<h1 data-ngcontent-c0=""> Welcome! </h1>
```